# Check if key is missing after loading json from file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting the JSON via:

```
with open("config.json") as data_file:
    global data
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

And I want to check if the `data["example"]` is empty or not.

Comment: Ok, what's your question? Have you tried anything? What's your sample data? Do you know how to get the length of a list?

Comment: Id like to check if the data["example"] existist in my json but when i try
if data["example"] == "" it says a error

Comment: Your question is unclear. It's hard to know if you're trying to test for the existence of the key "example", or the presence of a value against that key. I've done my best with my answer, but you really should include ALL the info you can (including errors and surrounding code)

Comment: Hey @PhilippKlos. Fancy marking one of the answers as the correct answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"example" in data.keys()` will return True or False, so this would be one way to check.

So, given JSON like this...

```
  { "example": { "title": "example title"}}
```

And given code to load the file like this...

```
import json

with open('example.json') as f:

    data = json.load(f)
```

The following code would return True or False:

```
x = "example" in data   # x set to True
y = "cheese" in data    # y set to False
```

Comment: You don't even need the `.keys()`; `in` by default checks for the existence of keys in a `dict`.

Comment: good point. I was being a little more explicit, but less pythonic in doing so. I'll amend my answer

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
if data.get("example") == "":
    ...
```

This will not raise an error, even if the key `"example"` doesn't exist.

What is happening in your case is that `data["example"]` does not equal `""`, and in fact there is no key `"example"` so you are probably seeing a `KeyError` which is what happens when you try to access a value in a dict using a key that does not exist. When you use `.get("somekey")`, if the key `"somekey"` does not exist, `get()` will return `None` and will return the value otherwise. This is important to note because if you do a check like:

```
if not data.get("example"): 
    ...
```

this will pass the if test if `data["example"]` is `""` *or* if the key `"example"` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
if isinstance(data, dict) and "example" in data and data["example"] != "":
        # example exists and holds something
```